# Add a column to sales order grid without breaking the order's view

Tags: magento2, order-grid

Here is the plugin code i tried to add the columns of the custom table to the sales order grid

```
<?php 
namespace Testing\Testorder\Plugins;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class AddColumnsSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName  
    ) {

        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();

                $select->joinLeft(
                   ['tt' => "Test_Testing"],
                   'main_table.increment_id = tt.order_id',
                   ['username']
                )->distinct();

            }

        }
        return $this->collection;
    }
```

but this will break the order's view page, there is an error when i click on the tabs like invoices/shipment/credit memos

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`order_id` = '26')

the plugin also breaks "All customers"

```
Notice: Undefined index: website_id in /home/m22/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Confirmation.php on line 69
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: The error message posted above states that there is no column called "order_id" in "sales_order_grid" table. In "sales_order_grid"  only "entity_id" field refers the order id. Also i don't understand in the Plugin Code why you are comparing increment_id with order_id both are different. Eg:- increment id will look like "000000001" and order id is what appears in the query parameter "sales/order/view/order_id/26/key"

Comment: @mydons the order_id is in my custom table Test_Testing

Comment: @mydons even i've change order_id -> something_id, the errors are exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make the below changes to your plugin code.** Clear your cache and reload the browser.

```
    public function aroundGetReport(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $requestName  
) {

    $result = $proceed($requestName); 
    if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
        if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
            $select = $this->collection->getSelect();

            $select->joinLeft(
               ['tt' => "test_testing"],
               'main_table.increment_id = tt.order_id',
               ['username']
            )->distinct();
           return $this->collection;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly